# React Authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Looking to add a login page to my app, but there aren't any up to date tutorials for react or react-router.

Thinking about passport js, and just having it reroute to my react app upon successful authentication.

Thoughts? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Auth0:** I'm a newbie myself, and spent a couple days on this exact question. It seems that Firebase, Okta, and Auth0 all have easy ways to add authentication to React. The simplest tutorial I found seems to be this [17 minute Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nE6TEDrBwWE), using Auth0. (The video itself uses Gatsby, but in the comments section you'll see a link using create-react-app instead.)

It relies mostly on an npm package called [react-use-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-auth).

Here is my [demo program on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mmskeen/tutorial-auth0-react) based on create-react-app (missing the Auth0 domain and client_id) with the important parts of the code pasted below.

index.js file:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { navigate } from "@reach/router";
import { AuthProvider } from "react-use-auth";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider
      navigate={navigate}
      auth0_domain="YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN"
      auth0_client_id="YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"
    >
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import { useAuth } from "react-use-auth";
import Callback from "./components/Callback";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, login, logout, user } = useAuth();

  const Login = () => {
      return isAuthenticated() ? 
        <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button> :
        <button onClick={login}>Login</button>;
  };

  const Greeting = () => {
    return isAuthenticated() ?
      <h1>Hi, {user.name}!</h1> :
      <h1>Hi there! Please login.</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Auth0 Example</h1>
      <Greeting />
      <Login />
      <Router>
        <Callback path="/auth0_callback" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

components/Callback.js:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "react-use-auth";

const Auth0CallbackPage = () => {
  const {handleAuthentication} = useAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    handleAuthentication();
  }, [handleAuthentication]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Logging in...</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth0CallbackPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can protect all routes with an `onEnter` callback

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Nav} >
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route path='/customers' component={Customers} onEnter={SignIn}/>
                <Route path='/vendors' component={Vendors} onEnter={SignIn}/>

        </Router>
      </Provider>
    ), document.getElementById('reactEntry'));
```

In the `SignIn` function, do what you need to check if the user can log in. If not, display error message

Also, here is a good example: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/30/react-okta-sign-in-widget